# Template compiler errors in gcc but not MSVC

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following template class (which I've stripped right down to leave just the error). It was meant to allow threadsafe access to a resource.

```
#include "boost/thread.hpp"

template<class T, class M>
class MyLockable {
public:
    template <template<typename> class L>
    int GetLocked();
};

template<class T, class M>
template <template<typename> class L>
int MyLockable<T, M>::GetLocked() {
    // Some code here
    return 0;
}
```

This worked fine, until I tried to use it from a templated class.

```
class NormalExample {
public:
    MyLockable<int, boost::shared_mutex> m_lockable;

    void FunctionOfNormal() {
        this->m_lockable.GetLocked<boost::shared_lock>();
    }
};

template <class T>
class TemplatedExample {
public:
    MyLockable<T, boost::shared_mutex> m_lockable;

    void FunctionOfTemplated() {
        this->m_lockable.GetLocked<boost::shared_lock>();
    }
};
```

The first example `FunctionOfNormal` works fine with no errors. The second example `FunctionOfTemplated` gives the error `missing template arguments before '>' token` and `expected primary-expression before ')' token`.

This error only happens in GCC (I'm using 4.9.4, C++14). Compiling with MSVC gives no errors. Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: `ths->m_lockable.template GetLocked<boost::shared_lock>();`

Comment: Jarod42, that worked perfectly, thank you!